# react router v4 authentication token keep redirecting to /

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

First of all here is my code:

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PUBLIC_ROUTE, LOGIN_ROUTE } from './utils/constants';

const routes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    let { requireAuth, isAuthenticated } = rest;

    if (!requireAuth) {
        requireAuth = false;
    }

    // If user authenticated
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        // If page need auth
        if (requireAuth === true) {
            return (
                <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />
            );
        } else if (requireAuth === 'partial') { // If the page is doesn't require auth but can't be access if auth true
            return <Redirect to={PUBLIC_ROUTE} />;
        }

        // If page doesn't need auth
        return <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />;
    }

    // If user not authenticated //

    // page doesn't require Auth
    if (requireAuth === false || requireAuth === 'partial') {
        return <Route {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props} />} />;
    }
    // If page require Auth redirect user to login routes
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: `${LOGIN_ROUTE}`,
                        state: { from: props.location },
                    }}
                />
            )}
        />
    );
};

routes.propTypes = {
    component: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
        React.PropTypes.element,
        React.PropTypes.func,
    ]),
};

export default routes;
```

**App.js**

```
const history = createHistory();

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { auth, global } = state;
    const { authenticated, user } = auth;
    const { loading } = global;

    return { authenticated, user, loading };
};

const reduxConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, { ping });

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
    };
    static propTypes = {
        authenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ isAuthenticated: nextProps.authenticated });
    }

    render() {
        const { authenticated, user, loading } = this.props;
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.state;

        if (loading) {
            return (
                <div style={style.center}>
                    <MDSpinner />
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <div>
                    <NotificationsSystem theme={theme} />
                    <Header isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} user={user} />
                    <NavMobile />
                    <SideMenu />
                    <Nav />

                    <Switch>
                        <Routes
                            requireAuth={false}
                            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                            exact
                            path="/"
                            component={Welcome}
                        />

                        <Routes
                            requireAuth={true}
                            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                            path="/point"
                            component={Point}
                        />

                        <Routes
                            requireAuth="partial"
                            isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
                            path="/login"
                            component={Login}
                        />

                        <Routes render={() => <h3>No Match</h3>} />
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer />

                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default reduxConnector(App);
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import cookie from 'react-cookie';

import { Headline, Section, renderField } from 'components';
import { ping } from 'redux/modules/auth';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { authenticated } = state.auth;

    return { authenticated };
}

const reduxConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, { ping });
const token = cookie.load('_t');

class Login extends React.Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        loggingIn: false,
        authenticated: false,
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        if(cookie.load('_t')){
            this.props.ping();
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        const { from } = this.props.location.state || {
            from: { pathname: '/' },
        };


        if (this.props.authenticated) {
            return <Redirect to={from} />;
        }

        return  <div>
                <Headline title="Login" />
            </div>;
    }
}

export default withRouter(reduxConnector(reduxFormDecorator(Login)));
```

Let say I already login to my app. And i want to navigate to `/point` (need auth to be access), app will `redirect` to `/login` after check the token (`this.props.ping()`):
1. If the token is valid: it will redirect me back to `point` page.
2. If the token is invalid: it will redirect me to `login` page.

The problem:

1. After checking and token is valid, the app always redirect to `/`. 
   I've `console.log` my `const {from}` the result is `{pathname: "/point", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: undefined}`. It never return back to previous page (in this situation `/point` page).
2. If I access '/' it never redirect to login to call `ping`. I need this because I've header that show user full name. So I need set the state to redux.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should understand that the `Redirect` works once after the component was mounted. You can not relay on it within the re-rendering. You may use `history.push()` API method instead.

Second, I'm not sure that I understood you solution properly, but seems you want to redirect somewhere just for setting some data to the `redux` store (can't find where are you dispatching a redux action). If it's true, it's a bad practice. You may do it within a dedicated action after logging in and you don't have to relate this logic to any component, then the redirection won't be required.

Comment: I think I got your idea. will try to implementing it .